# How to select second row of item in excel and paste into another excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on trying to find an item in an excel sheet and pasting information in an adjacent column. I need to strip the number in the first excel sheet of its hypens and then find it in the other document. I have had no issues with this, thus far, however when I try to select the second row I am getting a compilation error, saying line number or label was expected.

```
Sub info()

Dim dehyp As Long
Dim rng As Range

dehyp = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")
Sheets("Gov").Select

Set rng = Sheets("Gov").Columns(1).Find(What:=dehyp, LookIn:=xlFormulas, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Total usage").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End sub
```

Comment: Note: `Select`ing is not needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: So would I tried Set num = Sheets("Gov").Range(rng, 2)
        num.Copy, but I am getting a type mismatch now.

Comment: `Select` by itself is indeed a compilation error. Probably something like this will work - `rng.Offset(1).Select`, in order to select the next row? And in general, consider avoiding `Select` and `Activate`, as noted in the first comment.

Comment: That line makes no sense.  You never declare `num` as anything.  And the `range.copy` method doesn't return an object that you can set to something else.  Perhaps `rng.Offset(1,0).copy Sheets("Total usage").Range("B5")`